# Excel Visual Basic queryTables

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have an excel workbook. With visual basic I'm using a Connection:

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(Array( _
    "ODBC;DSN=Visual FoxPro Tables;UID=;;SourceDB=u:\MB\ABC Company;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine" _
    ), Array(";Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;")), Destination:=Range("L5"))
```

I need to connect with an sql server

what connection string should I use?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Yes, see the comment above.